# Creating a new POI Workbook but not save it

Tags: java, apache-poi

Is it possible to have Apache POI create and open a new Excel Workbook file, but not necessarily have it *saved* as a file? I'm trying to have it open as a short-term file, acting as if it were downloaded from the internet so that it could be saved if wanted, but otherwise deleted.

Comment: Why not just store the data that a POI workbook would have, and if the user chooses to save, only then generate the actual workbook?

Comment: @CeilingGecko I'm trying to create a reporting software from previous Excel data. If a user accidentally uses wrong parameters when creating the data, then it would be as easy as two button clicks rather than having to manually delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Excel opens files. Even the files that you open that have been "downloaded from the internet" are saved temporarily to either your designated downloads directory or the user's temporary directory.

You could save the workbook in the user's temporary directory (see [`Files.createTemporaryFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-)) and only move or copy it after the user has decided to keep it permanently. If they don't want to keep it, you can immediately delete it with [`File.delete()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete--) or when your application exits with [`File.deleteOnExit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit--).

Note that on Windows, both `File.delete()` and `File.deleteOnExit()` will only work consistently if you make sure that your application closes those files and their associated streams before attempting to delete them. The [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) is very helpful for this.

Comment: Thank you! As for the 'File.deleteOnExit()', how would the program know if the Excel file had been closed or not after the 'write()'?

Comment: It wouldn't. The OS would know the file was open and would prevent the delete from occurring. Just make sure that any stream that you create on a given file is properly closed. You can let the JRE do this for you if you use the try-with-resources statement that I linked to.